# Allow floating horizontal menu to resize with window without going to a new line

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a header with a small horizontal bar right underneath it that serves as the main navigation for my site. When the window is full sized it works perfectly. But if the window is resized even a little bit smaller, the right-most menu moves down to the next line, as you would expect any floated element to behave.

Question: How can I make it so the navigation bar always stays on one line, resizing appropriately to the window size? I've tried changing the lengths to percentages, though this often causes problems since there are many components to the CSS.

Here is all the relevant code: http://jsfiddle.net/HSVdg/1/

Here is what I think is the main culprit, though I could be wrong:

```
.menu2 li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    z-index: 1000
}
```

Some notes on the above link:

1. I am using Tiny Drop Down 2 (http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/tinydropdown2/) for drop-down functionality (in the form of JS and CSS, which are noted in comments), though the drop down is not actually working in the jsfiddle. I'm pretty sure all of the JS is irrelevant to my question.
2. The buttons are not vertically lined up with the actual bar, but again this is not the main issue since this is not happening on my actual site.
3. The window size in the jsfiddle doesn't actually accomodate the entire length of buttons, so you immediately see the problem of the buttons moving to the next line.

Any help would be immensely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using CSS display modes.

Just set the ul to have display:table
And the child list items to display: table-cell

The table cells will automatically adjust thir width to fill the parent table at any width.

You'll need to remove the explicit width from

```
<li>
```

and

```
<a>
```

to allow them to be automatic.

I've updated the fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/HSVdg/13/

Hope this helps.